# Hello. I need to show that $\sqrt n$ grows faster than $(\log n)^{100}$

Tags: asymptotics

Is there an easy way to show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {(\log n)^{100}}{\sqrt n}=0 $$

Comment: If the limit is 0 then $\sqrt n$ grows *faster* not slower than $\log^{100} n$

Comment: Do you mean faster?

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your question pretty heavily.  Please check to make sure I didn't introduce any errors.  In particular, I guessed that you meant $(\log n)^{100}$.  I might have gotten that wrong.

Comment: Consider the sequence $n=10^{2^k}$...

Comment: I meant $$ (logn)^{100}$$

Comment: You should react to the first comments.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the more general limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(\log(x))^{100}}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
Then use L'Hopital once to get:

$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(\log(x))^{100}}{\sqrt{x}}=200\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(\log(x))^{99}}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
Now repeat sufficient times to get:

$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(\log(x))^{100}}{\sqrt{x}}=K\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=0
$$

Hence for any sequence $a_n,\ n=1, ...$ for which $a_n\to \infty$ we have:

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(\log(a_n))^{100}}{\sqrt{a_n}}=0
$$

etc...

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for

Comment: The limit of $\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ is about as mysterious as $\frac{\log(x)^{100}}{\sqrt{x}}$. Why not apply L'Hôpital one more time to get $\frac{2^{100}100!}{\sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: @robjohn because I want to leave something to the OP to do

Answer (score 1):

Let $m=\log(n)$, then since $e^x\ge1+x\implies e^x\ge\left(1+\frac xk\right)^k$, let $k=101$
$$
\frac{\log(n)^{100}}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{m^{100}}{e^{m/2}}\le\frac{m^{100}}{\left(1+\frac{m}{202}\right)^{101}}\le\frac{202^{101}}m=\frac{202^{101}}{\log(n)}
$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Take $n=e^t$, and you need to show that $e^{t/2}$ grows faster than $t^{100}$.

Or, taking the $100^{th}$ root, $e^{t/200}$ grows faster than $t$.

Or by rescaling, $e^u$ grows faster than $200u$, which is the same as $e^{u}$ growing faster than $u$ (or $u$ faster than $\log(u)$).

Then for all $u>1$

$$\frac{\dfrac{e^{u+1}}{u+1}}{\dfrac{e^{u}}{u}}=e\frac{u}{u+1}>\frac e2$$

and $$\frac{e^u}u>\left(\frac e2\right)^u.$$

Comment: This uses induction, so the results are valid for integer $u$. However, since $u=\log(n)/200$, it is unlikely that $u$ is an integer.

Comment: @robjohn: this is only a hint. I am sure you will fill the gap without toil.

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
for any
$a>0$, $b > 0$,
$\lim_{n \to \infty}
\frac{(\log(n))^a}{n^b}
= 0
$.

There are a number of ways
to show this.
I like reducing this
to a standard form.

First,
replacing $n$
by $n^{1/b}$,

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\frac{(\log(n))^a}{n^b}
&=\frac{(\log(n^{1/b}))^a}{n}\\
&=\frac{(\log(n)/b)^a}{n}\\
&=\left(\frac{\log(n)}{bn^{1/a}}\right)^a\\
\end{array}
$

Then,
by replacing
$n$ by $n^a$,
this becomes

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\frac{(\log(n))^a}{n^b}
&=\left(\frac{\log(n)}{bn^{1/a}}\right)^a\\
&=\left(\frac{\log(n^a)}{bn}\right)^a\\
&=\left(\frac{a\log(n)}{bn}\right)^a\\
\end{array}
$

So,
if we can show that
$\lim_{n \to \infty}
\frac{\log(n)}{n}
=0
$,
by working backwards,
we can show that
$\lim_{n \to \infty}
\frac{(\log(n))^a}{n^b}
=0
$.

Note that these substitutions
can be combined
by replacing
$n$ by $n^{a/b}$.
We get

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(\log(n))^a}{n^b}
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(\log(n^{a/b}))^a}{(n^{a/b})^b}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{((a/b)\log(n))^a}{n^{a}}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{(a/b)\log(n)}{n}\right)^a\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

(1).For any $A>0$ we have $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\ln x)/x^A=0.$

Proof: For $x>0$ we have $$\ln x=\int_1^x (1/t)\;dt \quad\text { and }\quad  x^A= A(1+   \int_1^x (1/t^{1-A}\;dt\;).$$ Take any $E>0.$ Take $x_0>1$ such that $1/(x_0)^A<E A.$  For $t\geq x_0$ we have $$(1/t)/(1/t^{1-A})= 1/x^A\leq 1/(x_0)^A<E A.$$ $$\text {For } x\geq x_0 \text { we have } \ln x=\ln x_0+\int_{x_0}^t(1/t)\;dt\leq$$ $$\leq  \ln x_0+\int_{x_0}^x (E A)(1/t^{1-A})\;dt=$$ $$=E(x^A-(x_0)^A).$$So for $x\geq x_0$ we have $$0<(\ln x)/x^A\leq (-E (x_0)^A+\ln x_0)/x^A+E<(\ln x_0)/x^A+E.$$ From this, since $A>0$ implies $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\ln x_0)/x^A=0,$ we have $$0\leq  \lim_{y\to \infty} \sup_{x>y}\;[(\ln x)/x^A]\leq E \quad \text {for every } E>0.$$ $$\text {Therefore }\quad \lim_{x\to \infty}(\ln x)/x^A=0.$$ (2a). For any $B \ne 0$ and $C>0$ let $A=C/|B|.$ We have $A>0$ and we have $$\ln x>1\implies 0\leq |(\ln x)^B/x^C|\leq (\ln x)^{|B|}/x^C=$$ $$((\ln x))/x^A)^{|B|}$$ which tends to zero as $x\to \infty.$

(2b). For $B=0$ and $C>0$  we have,trivally,$x>1\implies  (\ln x)^B/x^C=1/x^C$, tending to $0$ as $x\to \infty.$

(3). For $r>0$ we have $\log_r x=(\ln x)/\ln r$ so for $C>0$ we have $|\log_r x)|^B/x^C=|\ln r|^{-B} \cdot |\ln x|^B/x^C$ which tends to $0$ as $x\to \infty.$